# High and low points on chart getting cut off

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The low and high points on this chart are getting cut off, is there any way to fix this *without* knowing what numbers will be in the data?

I've seen other people create some padding with the chart's minimum and maximum values, but I don't know what the values will be beforehand.

Chart:
[image]

A similar example suffering from the same problem is shown here: http://codepen.io/erose/pen/LNwdQO/

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.chart-container {
  width: 493px;
  height: 83px;
}

canvas {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

and here the JS used to create the above chart:

```
var ctx = $("#chart");

Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontFamily = "sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontSize = 20;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyColor = "#95989a";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyAlign = "left";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleFontSize = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleMarginBottom = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.footerMarginTop = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.cornerRadius = 12;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.caretSize = 10;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.xPadding = 20;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.yPadding = 10;
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = 'white';

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["            ", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "            "],
    datasets: [{
      label: '$',
      data: [100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,100,100],
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#2f75c1",
      borderCapSytle: "round",
      pointBorderColor: "#2f75c1",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#2f75c1",
      pointBorderWidth: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,

    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLkneColor: 'white',
        ticks: {
          display: false
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        // ticks: {
        //   display: false
        // }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: try adding padding to axis
http://c3js.org/reference.html#axis-x-padding
http://c3js.org/samples/axes_y_padding.html

Answer (score 4):

From reading your question I believe you not only want the for the circle to not be cut off but you would like some extra padding inside the chart.

For that I would structure this a little different:

```js
var ctx = $("#chart");

Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.maintainAspectRatio = false;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.display = false;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontFamily = "sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyFontSize = 20;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyColor = "#95989a";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.bodyAlign = "left";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleFontSize = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.titleMarginBottom = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.footerMarginTop = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.cornerRadius = 12;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.caretSize = 10;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.xPadding = 20;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.yPadding = 10;
Chart.defaults.scale.gridLines.color = 'white';
var getData = [100,100,100,100,0,100,100,100,100,100];
var getLabels = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""];
var minNum = function(array){
  return Math.min.apply( Math, array )-10;
}
var maxNum = function(array){
  return Math.max.apply( Math, array )+10;
}
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: getLabels,
    datasets: [{
      label: '$',
      data: getData,
      fill: false,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#2f75c1",
      borderCapSytle: "round",
      pointBorderColor: "#2f75c1",
      pointBackgroundColor: "#2f75c1",
      pointBorderWidth: 5,
      pointHoverRadius: 10,

    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLkneColor: 'white',
        ticks: {
          suggestedMin: minNum(getData), 
          suggestedMax: maxNum(getData),
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
        scaleLabel: {
          display: false
        },
        // ticks: {
        //   display: false
        // }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.chart-container {
  width: 493px;
  height: 83px;
}

canvas {
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>
```

2 Important changes

1. I create a getData var to hold the array this way the array can be formatted however you like the function does not care it just looks for getData and expects an array.
2. I created a minNum and maxNum function to go through the array and select either the lowest or highest number then call that inside the ticker you can find more on this at [ChartJS Scales](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales)