# ChartJS Line chart cut off at the top and bottom

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I'm using ChartJS to display some weather data. The problem I have is that the lines going right to the edge at the top and bottom look like they've been cut off.

[image]

I threw some example data together and uploaded it to this codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zELEWd

Is there some way to just add more space above the highest and the lowest point?

I read from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697409/chart-js-line-chart-is-cut-off-at-the-top) that there's the padding option, but that one affects the whole canvas and not the chart itself.

There are also some tips from [this stockoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398757/high-and-low-points-on-chart-getting-cut-off), but I can't really put a `suggestedMin` and `suggestedMax` value in there, since I have more than one dataset in there that all have slightly different min and max values. (eg. for Pressure[hPa] I don't want to set `suggestedMin` to 0, since its values are all somewhere around 1200)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've pretty much got it as is, just one configuration issue in the `options` object.

You currently have these options:

```
options: {
   title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Wetterdaten'
   },
   yAxes: [{
     ticks: {
       stepSize: 10
     }
   }]
}
```

but what is missing, is that the `yAxes` array property has to be inside of a `scales` object.  Like this:

```
options: {
   title: {
     display: true,
     text: 'Wetterdaten'
   },
   scales: {
     yAxes: [{
       ticks: {
         stepSize: 10
       }
     }]
   }
}
```

With this config in `options` your stepSize property will kick in and the top of the graph will be 20 when showing just the temperature data.

### BUT

Now that the `stepSize for the entire yAxis is 10`, the pressure dataset goes way out of wack.  So for this problem, you could implement two yAxes, where the pressure data is on the right yAxes and everything else is on the left yAxes:

```
var weatherCanvas = document.getElementById('weatherChart').getContext('2d');
var weatherChart = new Chart(weatherCanvas, {
    type: 'line',
    title: 'Wetter',
    data: {
        labels: ["01-01", "02-01", "03-01", "04-01", "05-01", "06-01", "07-01", "08-01", "09-01"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Temperature[°C]',
            data: [14, 18, 18, 16, 14, 11, 11, 11, null],
            borderColor: "rgb(252, 74, 74)",
            yAxisID: 'left-y-axis'
        }, {
            label: 'Windspeed[km/h]',
            data: [14, 18, 18, 16, 14, 11, 11, 11, null],
            borderColor: "rgb(101, 219, 255)",
            hidden: true,
            yAxisID: 'left-y-axis'
        }, {
            label: 'Humidity[%]',
            data: [84, 88, 88, 86, 74, 71, 71, 71, null],
            borderColor: "rgb(101, 155, 255)",
            hidden: true,
            yAxisID: 'left-y-axis'
        }, {
            label: 'Pressure[hPa]',
            data: [1193, 1211, 1211, 1200, 1999, 1997, 1995, 1993, null],
            borderColor: "rgb(211, 211, 211)",
            hidden: true,
            yAxisID: 'right-y-axis'
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'Wetterdaten'
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                id: 'left-y-axis',
                position: 'left',
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 10
                }
            }, {
                id: 'right-y-axis',
                position: 'right',
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 100
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Here is a [reference to Axes Configuration](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/master/docs/axes/cartesian) with a few examples as well.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Very cool, definitely helped make the chart look a lot nicer. As for now this solution works, but since this is a known bug I‘ll also keep an eye on any updates that fix that issue :)

Answer (score 2):

A very recent fix is shown [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/4971/commits/6501391e3072eba14961209aaaa88fad335a5b62).
You'd have to manually edit your Chart.js file `src/controllers/controller.line.js`
(For Angular 2, this file path will be located inside directory `node_modules/chart.js/`.)

Or just wait for the next Chart.js release which will most likely contain the fix.

An alternative workaround is described in comment 1 of this bug ticket: https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4202

Note that I posted the same comment to an identical question (though not for AngularJS):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47306019/3061684

Comment: Please make sure to post all the relevant information from your other answer to this one. Answers should not only consist of links but be valid on their own

Comment: I expanded my comment.