# Chart.js: Line displayed thinner than defined

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've created a simple line chart with a straight line, but if the line runs along the top and bottom horizontal grid line it is displayed thinner than defined. Even if the grid lines are hidden.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD58f.png

My code:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var config =  {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep", "Oct", "Nov"],
            datasets: [ {
                backgroundColor: "#ff0000",
                borderColor: "#ff0000",
                fill: false,
                borderWidth: 2,
                lineTension: 0,
                data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8]
            }]
        }, 
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    gridLines: { display: false }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    gridLines: { display: false }
                }]
            },
            legend: {
                display: false
            }
        }
    };          

    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This could be because the canvas ends there. Looks like the border is not included in the calculations of the line position. A jsfiddle would help a little bit :) You can also take a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37398757/high-and-low-points-on-chart-getting-cut-off

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I will test this approach. Here's my jsfiddle for the code above: https://jsfiddle.net/mwjdksxf/3/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chart.js line chart is cut off at the top?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697409/chart-js-line-chart-is-cut-off-at-the-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a litte bit. But the only solution i found which actually worked, was to add the space with the canvas helpers of chartjs. You can achieve this by adding the following code to your application:

```
var WIDE_CLIP = {top: 2, bottom: 4};

Chart.canvasHelpers.clipArea = function(ctx, clipArea) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
      clipArea.left,
      clipArea.top - WIDE_CLIP.top,
      clipArea.right - clipArea.left,
      clipArea.bottom - clipArea.top + WIDE_CLIP.bottom
    );
    ctx.clip();
}
```

Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46303679/4032712

I tried to use the padding and position options but none of the seems to work for your problem. Hope I could help you with this!

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks @Davide